# Поведение ботов в стратегиях

Tags: разработка-игр, искусственный-интеллект

В будущем хотел написать какую нибудь не сложною стратегию, но при обдумывании понял что понятия не имею как реализовать поведение ботов, а поиски в сети не дали результатов. Кстати игра будет напоминать серию игр Civilization, не знаете где можно было бы прочитать что нибудь на тему AI?

Comment: Я думаю вам стоит сперва написать игру и построить развитие бота скриптами, а после уже анализировать и делать его умней(сложней), если вы начнете со сложного механизма, то в программировании и разработке (если вы не профессионал) это может только оттолкнуть, а переделывать никогда не нужно бояться, сделайте простой вариант со сценариями а после двигайтесь дальше и делайте сложней и интересней!

Comment: Я думаю, сначала нужно определиться, какие ресурсы будут в вашей стратегии, в каком порядке нужно будет их собирать, какие из них самые значимые. Потом толкать на них бота. Вам также понадобится алгоритм Ли для того, чтобы находить кратчайшие пути до ресурсов.